# Finding the intersection of Gaussian distributions

Tags: matlab, gaussian

How can I find all the points where Gaussian mixture distributions intersect in MATLAB? 
[image]

Comment: https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/09/09/detect-curve-intersections-quickly-and-easily/

Answer (score 4):

The generic category of your question is finding the intersection of two curves, which is a manageable but non-trivial task (the hardest part is making sure you catch all the intersections).

But your problem is *very* specific: you're looking for the intersection of two Gaussians. This is very good: we both have an analytic formula for your function, *and* it's guaranteed that there are exactly two intersections unless some of your parameters are the same.*

Let's assume that your distributions are characterized by means `mu1`, `mu2` and scale `sigma1`, `sigma2`. Then your Gaussians at position `x` are defined by the function

```
1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2) * exp(-(x-mu)^2/2/sigma^2)
```

Turns out that we can fully solve this equation for `x` on paper:

```
1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma1^2)*exp(-(x-mu1)^2/2/sigma1^2) == 1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma2^2)*exp(-(x-mu2)^2/2/sigma2^2)
sigma2/sigma1 == exp((x-mu1)^2/2/sigma1^2) * exp(-(x-mu2)^2/2/sigma2^2)
log(sigma2/sigma1) == (x-mu1)^2/2/sigma1^2) - (x-mu2)^2/2/sigma2^2
```

which results in the parabolic equation `ax^2 + bx + c == 0` where

```
a = 1/(2*sigma1^2) - 1/(2*sigma2^2);
b = mu2/(sigma2^2) - mu1/(sigma1^2);
c = mu1^2/(2*sigma1^2) - mu2^2/(2*sigma2^2) - log(sigma2/sigma1);
```

It can be easily proved that the `D = b^2 - 4 a c` discriminant is non-negative, so indeed the equation has two real roots when the parameters aren't degenerate. So the two intersection points are, with the above definitions,

```
D = b^2 - 4 * a * c;
x1 = (-b + sqrt(D))/(2*a);
x2 = (-b - sqrt(D))/(2*a);
```

Using two gaussians with the pseudo-random parameters:

```
% define parameters and Gaussian
mu1=1; sigma1=3; mu2=2; sigma2=4;

% intersections
a = 1/(2*sigma1^2) - 1/(2*sigma2^2);
b = mu2/(sigma2^2) - mu1/(sigma1^2);
c = mu1^2/(2*sigma1^2) - mu2^2/(2*sigma2^2) - log(sigma2/sigma1)
D = b^2 - 4 * a * c;
x1 = (-b + sqrt(D))/(2*a);
x2 = (-b - sqrt(D))/(2*a);
```

Just to prove that the above intersection points are correct:

```
>> f = @(x,mu,sigma) 1/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2) * exp(-(x-mu).^2/2/sigma^2);
>> f(x1,mu1,sigma1) - f(x1,mu2,sigma2)

ans =

   2.7756e-17

>> f(x2,mu1,sigma1) - f(x2,mu2,sigma2)

ans =

   1.0408e-17
```

The above means that the values of the two Gaussians at points `x1` and `x2` are equal to one another within machine precision, which is as good as any numerical answer will get.

---

*I originally claimed that we always have two intersections as long as the Gaussians aren't exactly the same. Clearly if both the means and the variances are the same we have two degenerate curves and intersections become meaningless. But as [Cris Luengo pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021422/finding-the-intersection-of-gaussian-distributions/52021873#comment90994777_52021873), it might happen that there's only one intersection: when the variances are the same and the means are different (i.e. we have two curves of the exact same shape shifted along `x`). In this case `a=0`, consequently the corresponding equation is `b*x + c == 0`, giving us `x0 = -c/b` for the intersection. So a more exact (but a bit pseudo-codey) answer (given `a`, `b` and `c`) is

```
if a == 0 % or allow some tolerance... <=> sigma1 == sigma2
   if b == 0 % or allow some tolerance... <=> mu1 == mu2
      % degenerate curves: a == b == c == 0, f1(x)==f2(x) for all x
      disp('curves are degenerate...')
   else
      % single intersection: mu1 ~= mu2
      x1 = -c/b;
   end
else
   % two intersections; both parameters are different
   D = b^2 - 4 * a * c;
   x1 = (-b + sqrt(D))/(2*a);
   x2 = (-b - sqrt(D))/(2*a);
```

Comment: Are there always two intersections? How about the case where the variances are identical but the means are not? Wouldn’t there be only one intersection in that case?

Comment: @CrisLuengo your right: in that case `a=0` which exactly means that the equation is linear :) (the denominator would also be 0). Thanks for the correction!

Comment: LOL! — The intersection in between the two means is the optimal Bayes classifier. If you threshold there, you get best separation between the two classes described by the two Gaussians.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you for this. I've been looking for this formula for a long time. I built an example in Excel. However, the intercept is slightly off. I've quadruple checked that I've followed your formula exactly and I don't see an error. Finding `y` for the `x` intercept yields different results for each curve. Is there possibly a way I could contact you for some help with this? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @IamIC I might not be able to help if it's in excel, but in any case you can [open a chatroom for us](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak) (no promises for reliable availability, but I'll gladly take a look).